# Replacing UIAlertView by UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

Since `UIAlertView` is deprecated I want to replace it by `UIAlertController` in my old libraries.
But it is not always obvious to do. For example I have those two functions, doing a very similar task.

*showAlertViewMessageBox* uses `UIAlertView` and *showMessageBox* uses `UIAlertController`:

```
func showAlertViewMessageBox(_ msg:String, title:String, caller:UIViewController) {
    let userPopUp = UIAlertView()
    userPopUp.delegate = caller
    userPopUp.title = title
    userPopUp.message = msg
    userPopUp.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
    userPopUp.show()
}


func showMessageBox(_ msg:String, title:String, caller:UIViewController) {
    let attribMsg = NSAttributedString(string: msg,
                                       attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23.0)])
    let userPopUp = UIAlertController(title:title,
                                      message:nil, preferredStyle:UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    userPopUp.setValue(attribMsg, forKey: "attributedMessage")
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style:UIAlertAction.Style.default,
                                    handler:{action in})
    alertAction.setValue(UIColor.darkGray, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    userPopUp.addAction(alertAction)
    caller.present(userPopUp, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I want to use *showMessageBox* as much as possible. But I have this unhappy situation:

In the following code:

```
        //showMessageBox(usrMsg, title: popTitle, caller: self)
        showAlertViewMessageBox(usrMsg, title: popTitle, caller: self)
        quitViewController()
```

When using showAlertViewMessageBox, the message will pop up and stay there until I click the OK button.
(This is the behavior I want)

When using showMessageBox, the message will pop up as a blink and disappear without waiting for me to click the OK button.
(This is NOT the behavior I want)

How should I modify showMessageBox to get the behavior I want?

Comment: "When using showMessageBox, the message will pop up as a blink and disappear without waiting for me to click the OK button." I assume that this is *not* the default behavior, how/where are you calling `showMessageBox`?

Comment: Are you dismissing the viewController inside `quitViewController()` method?

Comment: Yes I am dismissing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are *dismissing the viewController inside quitViewController() method*, it is very natural that *the message will pop up as a blink and disappear without waiting for me to click the OK button*. As your `quitViewController()` method is executed without waiting for the OK button clicked.

One way, is adding a parameter to handle OK button clicking:

```
func showMessageBox(_ msg:String, title:String, caller:UIViewController, onOk: @escaping ()->Void) {
    let attribMsg = NSAttributedString(string: msg,
                                       attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23.0)])
    let userPopUp = UIAlertController(title:title,
                                      message:nil, preferredStyle:UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    userPopUp.setValue(attribMsg, forKey: "attributedMessage")
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style:UIAlertAction.Style.default,
                                    handler:{action in onOk()}) //<- Call the Ok handler
    alertAction.setValue(UIColor.darkGray, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    userPopUp.addAction(alertAction)
    caller.present(userPopUp, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Use it as:

```
    showMessageBox(usrMsg, title: popTitle, caller: self) {
        self.quitViewController()
    }
```

---

By the way, `attributedMessage` of `UIAlertController` and `titleTextColor` of `UIAlertAction` are private properties, so using this code may risk your app to be rejected by using private APIs.

Comment: OK. I will try. I understand the argument, but my showAlertViewMessageBox function works the way it is, like I want.

Comment: yes this solution works. Concerning your comment about the private properties, you may be right but, do you have a better suggestion to get the same result?

Comment: @Michel, I would use any of the default styles of `UIAlertController` or `UIAlertAction` where I can control the design. And if my client forced me to show alerts with custom styles, I would show, for example, a popup without using `UIAlertController`.